# Open a app by clicking on a tweet from twitter app on android

Tags: java, android, android-intent, twitter

I was looking for some way to launch my custom app from a Twitter app by clicking on a specific tweet.

The tweet may contain a link on which the user clicks and my app should be able open up.

As I understand I have two choices to do this with the intents.

1. Use a "custom-scheme within the data tag" of intent within my application.
2. Use a "http" scheme, with a specific url in the data tag of the intent within my application.

The problem with the first approach is if I use a custom scheme, the twitter will not recognize it as a link and there for it is not clickable.

The problem with the second approach is that if I have some thing like this in my android application :

```
<intent-filter . . . >
    <data android:scheme="http" android:host="project.example.com" />
. . .
</intent-filter>
```

and suppose if this is the tweet that the user clicks on :

***here is the link : [project.example.com](http://t.co/something)***

The twitter automatically will shorten the `project.example.com` to suppose say `t.co/something`

At which point the `intent-filter` listening to host `project.example.com` will render useless coz, the link is now shortened.

Except these approaches, I am not able to find the solution to the aforementioned problem.

As I have mentioned initially, all I want to do is open my android app when a user clicks on a particular tweet(Not all the tweets, just the intended tweet). How do I do this?

Any kind of help will be greatly appreciated.
TIA

Answer (score 1):

first of all add Intent filter in Manifest to yours Activity (what you will launch):

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <data android:scheme="any.thing.u.want"/>
        </intent-filter>
```

Second:
in your tweets add link

```
        any.thing.u.want://
```

For example, on JS it will be looked as

```
        document.location.href='any.thing.u.want://'
```

That's all :)
PS: Sorry for my English )

Comment: TS wrote that "The problem with the first approach is if I use a custom scheme, the twitter will not recognize it as a link and there for it is not clickable."

Comment: If I post this as a tweet : 'any.thing.u.want://p.example.com' that link will not be clickable. That is because the twitter thinks that it is not a URL.

Comment: @Slampy How to do that? can you please explain?

Comment: I dont have any kind of control on the twitter app where the use clicks the link, Except for tweeting the link

Comment: ooops. I thinked that u have control of twitter app. Sorry. U can use redirect on side page. I mean: u post tweet with link. User click on it. App redirect him to Browser, where redirect will be happen to any.thing.u.want://